# How do I send ETH from a simple wallet contract via MyEtherWallet?

Tags: myetherwallet

I used Ethereum Wallet to make a single wallet contract and sent it some ETH. When I load the keystore in MyEtherWallet, I can see the balance on the main account, however, I cannot see the balance on the wallet contract.

How do I see the the balance on the wallet contract, and send from this contract using MyEtherWallet (**not** Ethereum Wallet)?

Comment: On mobile but check https://myetherwallet.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/interacting-with-multisig-contracts & https://myetherwallet.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/how-do-i-check-the-balance-of-my-account

Comment: I use this as guide how to send coins from my contract address to its parent address, but every time it send inverted transaction... If i leave amount to send to 0 it take fee only and send nothing... When i put something like 0.1 it send from parrent address to contract address but i want to do opposite and then to send to some exchange because if i send direktly from contract to exchange i can wait for days...

Answer (score 1):

#### Getting Started

Go to the [Contract tab on MyEtherWallet.com](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts).

There should be a Mist Multisig Contract ABI in the dropdown. If not, you can manually use the ABI at the bottom of this page.

#### Do the Stuff

1. First, enter YOUR Contract Address in the `Contract Address` field at the top.
2. Second, you want to **EXECUTE**.

   1. Select `execute`from the dropdown.
   2. Enter the address you want to send to in the `_to`field.
   3. Enter the amount you want to send in the `_value`field.
   4. Leave the `data` field empty.
   5. *It is recommended that you test with a small amount first!*
   6. Unlock the owners address and click `WRITE` button.
   7. A pop up will appear. Leave `Amount to Send` as `0`.
   8. Click the `Generate Transaction` button & confirm & send.
3. Click the Transaction ID that outputs with the success message. Copy this ID.
4. If it's a multisig with TWO owners, you will need to refresh that page and choose **CONFIRM** this time.

   1. In step 3, you opened the TX ID from the `EXECUTE`call. You should have a page like this open: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0c643a1ae66637217f24791df05071c7849941a1231cf9fa2a0daf145da833e3
   2. Click the `Event Logs`tab.
   3. On the above link ([https://etherscan.io/tx/0x47e4cc87...#eventlog](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x47e4cc8748e296d9b5d85ebd9bd705177bb1940517b084a2efcca11feeb2391d#eventlog) - not YOUR link), the `_h` field would be `9228aeaf3ed560274899483646ea4ce9b322bccffac60cac2d035d08752617f4`
   4. Look at the above link and see where it says `9228a....`. Look at your link and see what YOUR `_h` is. Copy it.
   5. Go back to MyEtherWallet where you have the CONFIRM open and paste that hash into the `_h` field.
   6. Click the `"WRITE"` button again and unlock the second owner's account.
   7. Generate & send the transaction.
5. Make sure everything went as intended.
6. IF your multisig is a 3 of 5 multisig, you will repeat the confirm process for each owner until it reaches the necessary approvals. Luckily, the `_h`value is the same for each of them.
7. See another approval for my previous example here: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x47e4cc8748e296d9b5d85ebd9bd705177bb1940517b084a2efcca11feeb2391d#eventlog
8. You can then repeat this process whenever you want to send ETH.

#### Mist / Ethereum Wallet's Multisig Contract ABI

`[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"removeOwner","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_addr","type":"address"}],"name":"isOwner","outputs":[{"name":","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"m_numOwners","outputs":[{"name":","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"m_lastDay","outputs":[{"name":","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"version","outputs":[{"name":","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"resetSpentToday","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"m_spentToday","outputs":[{"name":","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"addOwner","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"m_required","outputs":[{"name":","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_h","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"confirm","outputs":[{"name":","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newLimit","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setDailyLimit","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"execute","outputs":[{"name":"_r","type":"bytes32"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_operation","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"revoke","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newRequired","type":"uint256"}],"name":"changeRequirement","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_operation","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"hasConfirmed","outputs":[{"name":","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"}],"name":"kill","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"}],"name":"changeOwner","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"m_dailyLimit","outputs":[{"name":","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_owners","type":"address[]"},{"name":"_required","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_daylimit","type":"uint256"}],"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"operation","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"Confirmation","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"operation","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"Revoke","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"oldOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnerChanged","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnerAdded","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"oldOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnerRemoved","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"newRequirement","type":"uint256"}],"name":"RequirementChanged","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Deposit","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"SingleTransact","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"operation","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"MultiTransact","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"operation","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":false,"name":"initiator","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"ConfirmationNeeded","type":"event"}]`

#### You can also copy the above from here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5nev1a/help_needed_how_to_find_multisig_contract_wallet/*

Comment: I think it's not clear, at least to a newbie like me. In MyEtherWallet tab Contract, I must open My Contract or Mist's Multisig Contract? Because I think you said both things.

Comment: Your ABI is malformed in several places. It seems some characters got lost during copy/pasting: `{"name":","type":"bool"}` is missing closing quotes for the empty `name` property for example.